# JsonDeserializer<T> deserialize-method not invoked on absent properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I have a simple, yet complex question: **is it possible to have a JsonDeserializer be invoked on missing JSON-properties?**

Why: I have a RegisterableProfile, which corresponds to a form the user has populated and sent to the server. In its most simple form it looks something like this:

**JSON-Request**, which will be mapped to a RegisterableProfile:

```
{
    "username": "someUser",
    "password": "somePass",
    "email": "some@mail.com",
    "language": "en"
}
```

The entity it's mapped onto (**RegisterableProfile**):

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@MappedSuperclass
public class RegisterableProfile extends CredentialsProfile {
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @OneToOne
    @Convert(converter = LanguageConverter.class)
    private Language language;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder(RegisterableProfile.class.getSimpleName())
                                                                           .append(" {")
                                                                           .append("name : '").append(getUsername()).append("',")
                                                                           .append("password : '").append(getPassword()).append("',")
                                                                           .append("email : '").append(email)
                                                                           .append("'}")
                                                                           .toString();
    }
}
```

Note, that CredentialsProfile simply provides the username and password and is separated from this class, because on an initial login it may occur separately.

**Language** entity:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LanguageDeserializer.class)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "Languages")
public class Language {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String  languageCode;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String  name;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String  i18nName;
    private boolean localizeUi      = false;
    private boolean canChoose       = false;
    private boolean defaultLanguage = false;
}
```

The "language"-property in the JSON-String is converted properly into a Language-object using the LanguageDeserializer - **if the property is present**.
However: if the **property is missing or null**, the LanguageDeserializer#deserialize method is not invoked and "language"-attribute in RegisterableProfile stays null.

I probably could work around this problem by checking whether language-attribute is "null" inside my ProfileService-method and setting it there if so, but it does not seem as clean as having the custom Deserializer be invoked on the missing property.

Another idea (still rather a workaround) would be to have a custom deserializer for RegisterableProfile as well and have it detect if language-property is missing or something, but I have no idea how to go about it.

My **LanguageDeserializer**:

```
public class LanguageDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Language> {

    @Autowired
    private LanguageService languageService;

    @Override
    public Language deserialize(final JsonParser p, final DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        final JsonNode node = p.readValueAsTree();
        final String languageCode = node.asText();
        return languageService.getLanguage(languageCode);
    }
}
```

Note: languageService.getLanguage(...) always returns either an Language-object matching the languageCode or the default Language-object.

Furthermore: a solution should be working with spring-boot (and its stack of libraries). I am currently using spring-boot version 1.5.7.RELEASE and 2.8.10 (bundled with spring-boot).

Answer (score 0):

## Missing Language Property Updates

If you expect language property to be missing, you can write a `BeanDeserializerModifier` which delegates the creation of `RegisterableProfile` to the default deserializer. It creates the complete `Language` object based on the value provided. If the language property is completely missing, use a default value. Here][1](https://github.com/indrabasak/stackoverflow-indra/tree/master/spring-test-examples) is a working example.

#### RegisterableProfile Deserializer Delegates to Default Deserializer

```
package com.divstar.particle.authservice.rest.accountservice.mapper;

import com.divstar.particle.authservice.rest.languageservice.LanguageService;
import com.divstar.particle.authservice.rest.tos.RegisterableAccount;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ResolvableDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RegisterableAccountDeserializer
        extends StdDeserializer<RegisterableAccount>
        implements ResolvableDeserializer {

    private final JsonDeserializer<?> defaultDeserializer;

    private LanguageService languageService;

    public RegisterableAccountDeserializer(
            JsonDeserializer<?> defaultDeserializer,
            LanguageService languageService) {
        super(RegisterableAccount.class);
        this.defaultDeserializer = defaultDeserializer;
        this.languageService = languageService;
    }

    @Override
    public RegisterableAccount deserialize(JsonParser parser,
            DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        RegisterableAccount account =
                (RegisterableAccount) defaultDeserializer.deserialize(parser,
                        context);

        if (account.getLanguage() != null && account.getLanguage().getLanguageCode() != null) {
            account.setLanguage(
                    languageService.getLanguage(
                            account.getLanguage().getLanguageCode()));
        } else {
            account.setLanguage(languageService.getLanguage("en"));
        }

        return account;
    }

    @Override
    public void resolve(
            DeserializationContext context) throws JsonMappingException {
        ((ResolvableDeserializer) defaultDeserializer).resolve(context);
    }
}
```

#### Spring Configuration

```
package com.divstar.particle.authservice.rest.config;

import com.divstar.particle.authservice.rest.accountservice.mapper.RegisterableAccountDeserializer;
import com.divstar.particle.authservice.rest.languageservice.LanguageService;
import com.divstar.particle.authservice.rest.tos.RegisterableAccount;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanDescription;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerModifier;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;

@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder(
            final LanguageService service) {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();

        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.setDeserializerModifier(new BeanDeserializerModifier() {
            @Override
            public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyDeserializer(
                    DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc,
                    JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
                if (beanDesc.getBeanClass() == RegisterableAccount.class) {
                    return new RegisterableAccountDeserializer(deserializer,
                            service);
                }

                return deserializer;
            }
        });

        builder.modules(module);

        return builder;
    }
}
```

#### Changes to RegisterableAccount

Commented out the line `this.language = Language.getDefaultLanguage()`.

```
public class RegisterableAccount extends Credentials {
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @OneToOne
    @Convert(converter = LanguageConverter.class)
    private Language language;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public RegisterableAccount() {
        // set language to default; will be overridden if valid languageCode is provided
        //this.language = Language.getDefaultLanguage();
    }
    ...

}
```

#### Changes to LanguageDeserializer

```
public class LanguageDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Language> {

    @Override
    public Language deserialize(final JsonParser p, final DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        final JsonNode node = p.readValueAsTree();
        final String languageCode = node.asText();

        if (languageCode != null) {
            Language language = new Language();
            language.setLanguageCode(languageCode);
            return language;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! However: I am having troubles. I followed your code samples and even added a no-args constructor for the LanguageDeserializer (because otherwise I got a JsonMappingException stating there is no no-args constructor oon request). After adding a no-args constructor, on request I receive: Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public ...PersistableProfile ...profileservice.ProfileController.registerAccount(...RegisterableProfile).  getObject() seems incomplete, too. Any idea?

Comment: Correction: on spring-boot startup the CustomObjectMapperFactory is used and it seems to successfully create a custom ObjectMapper with the languageService and the LanguageDeserializer in it. HOWEVER: adding the empty constructor to LanguageDeserializer leaves the LanguageService in it empty, resulting in a NullPointerException. Removving it results in a JsonMappingException stating that the deserializer does not have a no-args constructor. I am wondering why it is trying to construct another LanguageDeserializer-object - I thought we used addDeserializer to add an initialized object...?

Comment: Try making the language service auto wired in the deserializer with a default constructor. Looks like Spring is trying to create the deserializer by reflection (Spring managed).

Comment: I tried and I even got the instance of the LanguageDeserializer by injecting a BeanFactory into the CustomObjectMapperFactory and invoking beanFactory.getBean(LanguageDeserializer.class). The problem remains the same as it was in the beginning: the LanguageDeserializer#deserialize-method is not invoked if the property "language" does not exist in the JSON-request(body). If it is, it all works as before.

Comment: Updated my posting. I tested it. It should work now.

Comment: It's odd. I set a breakpoint inside the ObjectMapperBuilder-bean and the deserializer in there has a properly set LanguageService-attribute, but when I set a breakpoint inside the LanguageDeserializer-class this very attribute is null (almost as if it was not properly @Autowired). I used your LanguageDeserializer implementation. Do you happen to have an idea why that is? Furthermore: the LanguageDeserializer is still not invoked if the language-property in the JSON is missing. Perhaps I should make a ghist or something to show you the project?

Comment: Thank you for the update! Your implementation of BookDeserializer works. What I would like though is to **reuse the default deserialization** mechanism for everything - **except the "language"-property**. I think the combination of what you showed me along with some mix-in would be what I am looking for, but I cannot get it to work. Injecting ObjectMapper into RegisterableProfileDeserializer and using e.g. convertValue causes infinite recursion - which is sad, but kinda expected. You already helped me a lot, but would you happen to have an idea about this as well? Thank you very much!

Comment: Updated my posting to use default deserializer for `RegisterableProfile`. Please check out my example again.

Comment: I tried the update you provided, but it still does not work. I take it that you did not mean to write "LanguageDeserializer" in the objectMapperBuilder-bean, right? Anyway - I tried what I could, but it keeps trying to create an instance of RegisterableProfileDeserializer, failing with a JsonMappingException (RegisterableProfileDeserializer has no default (no arg) constructor). I tried adding @Component to RegisterableProfileDeserializer, but it did not help as then it warns me about forming a cycle.

Comment: You don't need `LanguageDeserializer`. My example works. I can take a look at your project if you check your project in GitHub.

Comment: Thank you. Here is the link to my project: https://github.com/divStar/particle-authservice . It currently does not contain any of the changes you suggested, because I solved my particular issue by using "initOnApplicationReady()" with "@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)" (in class "LanguageServiceImpl") and initializing a default language on startup. I would be very happy if you could add your latest suggested changes (or give me some particular hints on how to do it myself) :).

Comment: I know it is a bit late, but would you mind perhaps sharing your adjusted sample? I worked around the issue for now, but I'd like to finally solve this issue in order to mark this question as answered.